# Save new object at index path Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor, nsindexpath

Every time I Save a new Object it appears on the top of my `UITableView`. What If want it to apper at a different index path or different section?

For Example is it Possible to insert  the new Object at:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[self objectsFetched] count]-1 inSection:0];
```

or

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[self objectsFetched] count]-1 inSection:1];
```

I Can accomplish the above scenario with `NSMutableArray`s, but how do I achieve the same with Core Data?

Comment: Take a step back.  How does saving an object to an index path translate to a position in core data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Core Data you have a big bag of contents, how you display that in a table view is entirely up to you. The process of achieving this is by sorting the big bag, generally as you extract the contents.

Look at `NSFetchRequest` and you will see it takes an array of `sortDescriptors`. You can make these sort descriptors look at any key in your managed objects. If you want, you can add an explicit `order` key and set the value, or a date stamp.

How you sort is up to you, but you do need to sort to specify the order you want.